# Retrieve Just A Element From Mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm trying to retrieve just a lesson from a classes collection based on it's id. I put together the following from previous answers, but it doesn't return anything. Can someone point me in the right direction?

*My Code*

```
Class.aggregate([
    {$match: {'lessons._id': id}},
    {$project: {
        lessons: {$filter: {
            input: '$lessons',
            as: 'lesson',
            cond: {$eq: ['$$lesson._id', id]}
        }},
        _id: 0
    }}
])
```

*Example*

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("14354"),
    "title" : "Easy Math",
    "instructor_id" : "2454",
    "lessons" : [
        {
            "lesson_body" : "2 + 2 = 4",
            "lesson_title" : "Addition",
            "_id" : ObjectId("3456")
        },
        {
            "lesson_body" : "4 - 2 = 2",
            "lesson_title" : "Subtraction",
            "_id" : ObjectId("4456")
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5345"),
    "title" : "Harder Math",
    "instructor_id" : "6345",
    "lessons" : [
        {
            "lesson_body" : "2 * 2 = 4",
            "lesson_title" : "Multiplication",
            "_id" : ObjectId("7454")
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be `lessons` instead of `lesson`

on this line :
`cond: {$eq: ['$$lessons._id', id]}`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you:

```
db.COLLECTION_NAME.find({ lessons: { $elemMatch: { "_id" : ObjectId("3456")} } })
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally sure, but remember having similar issues. Also I think your syntax looks somewhat strange? Try to adapt to this, this is how I have learned it should look atleast:

```
var objectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
```

And then when you try to get the object by ID:

```
db.collection("classes").findOne({"_id": new ObjectID(id)}
```

Feel free to find inspiration here: [github repository](https://github.com/hilleer/MeanPeriod3/blob/master/Application/model/jokes.js)